# how do you parse txt file to validate if metadata data exists using R

Tags: r

There are thousands of files. I need to read these files and make sure certain fields (meta data) exist and and have values.

this is the content of the file:

```
good file:


SERVER_GROUP=TESt
SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES="SERVER_TIER=tier2 SERVER_PURPOSE=GENERAL SERVER_PROVIDER=AZURE SERVER_REGION=NA"
TENANT=1234567

bad file: 
SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES="SERVER_TIER=tier2 SERVER_PURPOSE=GENERAL SERVER_PROVIDER=AZURE SERVER_REGION=NA"
meda_data <-c("SERVER_GROUP", "SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES", "SERVER_TIER", "SERVER_PURPOSE", "SERVER_PROVIDER", "SERVER_REGION", "TENANT"

con <- file("C:\\test.txt", "r", blocking = FALSE)
dat<-readLines(con)

dput(dat)
c("SERVER_GROUP=TESt", "SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES=\"SERVER_TIER=tier2 SERVER_PURPOSE=GENERAL SERVER_PROVIDER=AZURE SERVER_REGION=NA\"", 
"TENANT=1234567")
```

If the file test.txt has all of the metadata as in this example (dat), the file should be added text.good. if any of the meta data fields are missing or have no value assigned to them, the file should be renamed text.bad.

Is there any library, I can leverage to confirm each file has the medatdata in it.

Comment: what do you mean by *has all the metadata and have values*? can you elaborate that using your dput data? ie is this file good? if so why?

Comment: You could use the base function `strsplit` (with `sep = "="`) to split the field names and their values. Then `strsplit` the value of `SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES` with `sep = " "`, and `strsplit` again. The annoying thing is that the value of `SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES` is quoted. You'd be better off using a package that can process this type of envvar file.

Comment: In my experience, this kind of server related data is generally available in JSON or YAML format, which are much easier to parse, especially with nested fields like `SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES`.

Comment: @Onyambu, there are some fields, I call them medata that they need to exist in all files. In this case the file is called "text.txt".

Comment: @asac, this info is custom, not available in json or jaml. Simple txt file.

Comment: @Onyambu, I need to check all meda data values in meda_data should exist in text.txt with values.

Comment: That is exactly what I said you should not say. Let me break it down to you What are the so called *all meta_data values*?

Comment: @Onyambu, those are the fields (variables) need to exist in test.txt file. For example, SERVER_GROUP=TESt. SERVER_GROUP has value TESt and so forth. I need to see all values in meta_data vector exist and have values in test.txt file.

Comment: so is your example above a valid text?

Comment: @Onyambu, yes. Above test.txt is a good file.

Comment: What is an example of non-valid?

Comment: @Onyambu, I just updated the post with bad file. That is an example of a bad file. In this case SERVER_GROUP is missing in test.txt. If any of the meda_data values is missing from test.txt, it is a bad file.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can `gregexpr` for any non-space, non-`=` before every `=` to get all of the variable names.

```r
is_valid <- function(file, text, ..., fields = NA) {
  if (missing(fields)) {
    fields <- c("SERVER_GROUP", "SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES", "SERVER_TIER",
                "SERVER_PURPOSE", "SERVER_PROVIDER", "SERVER_REGION", "TENANT")
  }
  if (missing(text)) {
    text <- readLines(file, ...)
  }
  found <- gsub("['\"]", "", unlist(regmatches(text, gregexpr("[^\\s=]+(?==)", text, perl = TRUE))))
  ret <- all(fields %in% found)
  attr(ret, "missing") <- setdiff(fields, found)
  attr(ret, "extra") <- setdiff(found, fields)
  ret
}

is_valid(text = dat1)
# [1] TRUE
# attr(,"missing")
# character(0)
# attr(,"extra")
# character(0)

is_valid(text = dat2)
# [1] FALSE
# attr(,"missing")
# [1] "SERVER_GROUP" "TENANT"      
# attr(,"extra")
# character(0)

is_valid(text = dat3)
# [1] TRUE
# attr(,"missing")
# character(0)
# attr(,"extra")
# [1] "QUUX"

is_valid(text = dat4)
# [1] FALSE
# attr(,"missing")
# [1] "SERVER_GROUP" "TENANT"      
# attr(,"extra")
# [1] "QUUX"
```

This can be easily plugged into any mechanism that renames or filters or whatever to the files. Taking `dat1` and saving to `"dat1.txt"` (etc), we can do

```r
filenames <- paste0("dat", 1:4, ".txt")
valids <- sapply(filenames, is_valid)
valids
# dat1.txt dat2.txt dat3.txt dat4.txt 
#     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE 
goods <- filenames[valids]
bads <- filenames[!valids]
paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(goods), ".good.txt")
# [1] "dat1.good.txt" "dat3.good.txt"
file.rename(goods, paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(goods), ".good.txt"))
file.rename(bads, paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(bads), ".bad.txt"))
```

---

Data

```r
dat1 <- 'SERVER_GROUP=TESt
SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES="SERVER_TIER=tier2 SERVER_PURPOSE=GENERAL SERVER_PROVIDER=AZURE SERVER_REGION=NA"
TENANT=1234567'
dat2 <- 'SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES="SERVER_TIER=tier2 SERVER_PURPOSE=GENERAL SERVER_PROVIDER=AZURE SERVER_REGION=NA"'
dat3 <- 'SERVER_GROUP=TESt
SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES="SERVER_TIER=tier2 SERVER_PURPOSE=GENERAL SERVER_PROVIDER=AZURE SERVER_REGION=NA QUUX=1230984"
TENANT=1234567'
dat4 <- 'SERVER_CUSTOM_PROPERTIES="SERVER_TIER=tier2 SERVER_PURPOSE=GENERAL SERVER_PROVIDER=AZURE SERVER_REGION=NA QUUX=1230984"'
```

Comment: user1471980, certainly not a rush, but have you looked at this yet? Does it work with the rest of your (real) data?